# Windows Authentication SSO in ASP.NET Remote Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, single-sign-on

There is a requirement to implement *Single Sign On (SSO)* in our website so that users accessing it from the intranet won't have to type in their credentials.

The problem here is that the website is going to be hosted on the internet, on a remote server.

Is there some way this can be done?

--EDIT--

I looked at following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services

And the example scenario that is mentioned in there is exactly what we require.

#### Here is the detailed explanation on the situation:

There is an *Active Directory Domain Controller* that is used to authenticate users in the intranet.

Once the user logs into the machine, and opens up the remote website, the website should somehow verify that the user is already logged into the intranet using AD credentials and automatically allow access to the website.

Also, the website is supposed to be getting a *Security Token* that can be used to authenticate the user.

Comment: A more complete description of Authentication might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, for example, Microsoft's way of doing that for connecting Office365 to your Intranet is called [Active Directory Federation Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services).

It is (as most single sign on solutions) not entirely straight forward, and it assumes a domain on your intranet, but since Office365 uses it, it is and will most likely continue to be well supported in the future.

Comment: The example mentioned in the article is exactly what I want. Can you provide any pointers that can help me integrate/use ADFS with ASP.NET?

Comment: @Sharp.Extensions [This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alextch/archive/2011/06/27/building-a-test-claims-aware-asp-net-application-and-integrating-it-with-adfs-2-0-security-token-service-sts.aspx) has info on getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of integrating your web app with the authentication provider that you are using for SSO.  The details are going to vary dramatically if your using OAuth vs. Shibboleth vs. ADFS vs. etc, so there really isn't enough information in your question to give a helpful answer.

Comment: Since the Intranet is using *Active Directory Domain Controller* to authenticate the users, I am guessing ADFS is the choice here.